# Where is the blockchain saved in Mac?

Tags: monerod, macos

I would like to delete the blockchain files from my computer. Where are these files located by default?

Comment: more of a question is it still hidden in custom setting

Answer (score 9):

It is stored in `/Users/[your username here]/.bitmonero`

Example: `/Users/sgp/.bitmonero`

The `.bitmonero` folder is hidden by default, but it is there. The easiest is to open a Finder, hit `CMD+SHIFT+G` (keyboard shortcut for "Go to folder") and enter the path to open that location.

Comment: Or you press `CMD+SHIFT+.` in finder to show all the hidden stuff