# How to remove monero-wallet-gui from mac

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining, synchronization

I am entirely new to crypto and monero so I figured I would download the monero-wallet-gui from getmonero.org. I downloaded the mac version and then I started the syncing process not knowing what it was. I noticed my computer was running slowly so I checked my computer's storage.

My storage was almost 100% full!

I am assuming this is because I was unknowingly downloading he entire monero blockchain onto my computer.

Anyway, long story short I just want to remove the monero-wallet-gui and everything that I synced from my computer. I have no idea how to do this. I really would like my computer to go back to the way it was before I downloaded the monero-wallet-gui from getmonero.org.

I did remove the monero-wallet-gui app from my applications folder. I am not sure if that fixed the issue though.

Please help as my computer is running very slowly now unfortunately.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The blockchain (on Linux and Mac) is stored at `~/.bitmonero`. See [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/6778/7493) which describes how to find it, then simply delete. If you're short on storage you can run a [pruned](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11454/how-do-i-utilize-blockchain-pruning-in-the-gui-monero-wallet-gui) blockchain instead, or even connect to a remote node.

Comment: I don't see .bitmonero in my ~/ directory. Could it be in another directory? I deleted the app and I noticed that the amount of free storage I have on my hard drive keeps increasing every time I check it. Could it be that the block chain actually was deleted, but my hard drive's garbage collection just hasn't gotten around to actually cleaning it up? If not, why does my free storage amount keep going up every once in a while?

Comment: Did you follow steps in linked answer?? CMD+SHIFT+G (keyboard shortcut for "Go to folder") then type ~/.bitmonero Obviously you need to empty the Trash after too.

Comment: Hidden directories are not shown be default on the Mac in Finder.  Can do it via the Terminal.  (People shouldn't be afraid of the terminal. Some things are actually a lot easier.)

Comment: I found and removed the ~/.bitmonero directory, but when I look at my macs storage I still have about 86 GB dedicated to "other". This was not like this before. This leads me to believe there are still some things from the GUI that I downloaded saved on my computer. How do I get rid of that? That is what I want to do. I want my computer to be exactly how it was before I downloaded the monero-wallet-gui. I want a clean uninstall. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

on Linux: You have to remove folder .bitmonero and folder Monero in your home folder, then delete folder Monero-gui in you remote loading